How do we Customize iPadOS 18 Tab Bar Background Color
with the new iPadOS update, Apple has implemented a new tab bar. im trying to customize my existing tab bar to have this dark background color. But natively, its using this whiter/grey background. I'm having trouble finding in documentation on how to update this background color. Can someone provide some insight?



It is currently not possible to change the background color of this bar, only the text color can be set.
The background color is automatically set by the system appearance.
See the answer from an Apple engineer here.

yes, i just found out how apple did it for their demos too.
Its by setting this.
.preferredColorScheme(.dark)

Yes, the appearance of the bar can be influenced by setting the color scheme. But you have to be careful if you support iOS in addition to iPadOS, as this can otherwise have unwanted side effects under iOS.
It should also be noted that even tab bar specific UIAppearance proxies won't have an effect on this new floating tab bar. I hope that Apple will improve this soon, but I fear that this won't happen any time soon.
